# What happens to a greenhouse gas after it absorbs infrared radiation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, bond, photochemistry, green-chemistry

We say that a greenhouse gas increases the temperature of the surface of the earth but how does it do that ? Only by re emitting the absorbed IR towards the earth ?

Answer (score 5):

Actually a greenhouse gas absorbs light in the infrared wavelengths of light (longwave in the picture). One of two things will happen after the gas absorbs the IR radiation: 1) the molecules to move around and vibrate faster, which is really the definition of temperature, so the air gets warmer, and 2) the gas molecules can re-emit the IR radiation. In the second case, the radiation is emitted isotropically, so that some of it just goes out into space as it would have had the gas not been there in the first place, but some of it will be directed back towards the surface of the earth, warming the surface by absorption of the IR (heat).

[image]
Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Atmospheric_radiation.png

Note that most of the heat being absorbed by greenhouse gases is coming from the ground after the ground absorbs sunlight and warms up, not from the sun shining through the air and being absorbed by the greenhouse gases directly.

Answer (score 5):

The 'greenhouse' gases such as $\ce{CO2, H2O, CH4}$ absorb infrared radiation and become vibrationally and rotationally excited. When excited, their temperature is effectively greater than that of their surroundings.

Two things can now occur; the vibrationally excited molecules may radiate, some of this energy will be lost to space, and some absorbed by the Earth and can therefore be re-radiated. Secondly, a collision with other air molecules will compete with radiating and thus transfer some, or all, of the extra vibrational/rotational energy to the collision partner until, after several collisions, all gases are at the new equilibrium temperature. This increase in temperature can only occur because the majority gases in the atmosphere, nitrogen and oxygen, cannot radiate infrared radiation as they have no electric dipole. Thus, the energy is trapped as vibration and rotational energy in the ground state of these molecules and therefore after collisions with other molecules transfers this energy and so heats up the atmosphere.

Comment: The last 2 sentences are confusing and inaccurate. The heat is contained in the increased KE of the various molecules. The various states are populated dependent on the temperature for O2 and N2. Look up the Raman spectra of these gases.

Comment: No, You are wrong in this assertion about the accuracy of these statements. Raman is a scattering process, it does not occur spontaneously but only via a photon already there and it is not efficient anyway. A molecule with a dipole can radiate and absorb (ir) radiation to come into equilibrium with its surroundings. As there is no dipole on O2/N2 they cannot do this and so get hotter and spread their energy to other molecules via collisions. Hence a hotter atmosphere.

Comment: I have to agree that at least the final sentence isn’t quite right. The temperature is a function of the translational KE only, not the rotation and vibration energy levels, though equipartition means that all three increase equally as the system equilibrates (neglecting vib modes that are inaccessible)

Comment: Raman spectroscopy is a means of examining the rotational and vibrational levels occupied by O2 and N2. The increase in temperature comes from collisional deactivation of excited CO2 molecules by other molecules increasing the temperature. If appreciable energy is stored in higher excited states of N2 and O2 then Raman analysis should reveal it.  I am not aware of a study showing transfer of energy from an excited CO2 molecule to excite an O2 or N2 molecule[interesting possibility].  The comment specified ground state. Energy in excited states does not increase T until they are deactivated.

Comment: A few points in reply to comments. I was not talking about excited states just vibrational/rotational levels in the ground state. Raman has both stokes and anti stokes transitions so effect will be small on population overall, and as mentioned Raman probability is small. Collisions can transfer energy all over the place, i.e. not restricted as are dipole transitions. There is a vibrational and rotational temperature ( as described by Boltzmann distribution) in a molecule before thermalisation that can be different to the average; this is why energy gets spread. I have clarified last sentence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138218/discussion-on-answer-by-porphyrin-what-happens-to-a-greenhouse-gas-after-it-abso).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the point made by airhuff, which is that greenhouse gases essentially prevent the earth from emitting infrared radiation into space, this slight effect shifts the equilibria of greenhouse gases which actually amplifies the effect.

That is to say, when people speak of $\ce{CO2}$ being a big problem, this mostly  because of an indirect effect. $\ce{CO2}$ slightly warms the earth which increases the amount of water vapor present in the atmosphere (in an average sort of way because this fluctuates quite a bit). This is a problem because water is a much more potent greenhouse gas than $\ce{CO2}$ and it absorbs at different wavelengths in the IR than $\ce{CO2}$ does. This matters because the amount of IR which $\ce{CO2}$ absorbs is fairly close to saturation. That is, doubling the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ does not mean doubling the amount of IR radiation absorbed and redirected back towards earth. The relationship is much closer to logarithmic than linear. But, this is only true for the wavelengths at which $\ce{CO2}$ absorbs, so introducing more water vapor allows a wavelength of IR to be absorbed which may not be saturated.

This is only one mechanism by which greenhouse gases warm the earth. The atmosphere is an extremely complicated system. None of this mentions how well certain gases mix in the atmosphere and how long they stay there and anything about methane for that matter. All of these things have been written about in scholarly articles and books, so those are gonna be the places you find the nitty-gritty details and data.

Also a note on what I mean when I say carbon dioxide is roughly saturated in terms of absorbance. It is true that carbon dioxide quite effectively absorbs IR light, but it can never truly be saturated. This is because the relationship is logarithmic, so it always increases, but just more slowly as you add more $\ce{CO2}$. Second, it has been said that convection can play an important role here because one shouldn't really think of bulk concentration of carbon dioxide but really the concentration in different layers of the atmosphere. This complication actually allows $\ce{CO2}$ to absorb more radiation than you might otherwise expect.

Answer (score 2):

The high level effect of green gases is, they cause Earth as a planet, at the same surface temperature, emits to space less IR energy (at affected wavelengths) than without them.

With addition of GH gas, this IR is emitted to space more by high altitude cold gas and less by low altitude warm surface. That leads to disbalance of net energy until Earth surface temperature in mean levels increases.

As surface has to emit at IR windows from surface the extra energy, than is not emitted by GH gases. ( my meteorology background speaking)

Comment: Good overview!   The details sometimes just get in the way.